# Trying to use a SQL function in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to use [this script](http://blog.netnerds.net/2007/01/t-sql-parse-top-level-domain-from-url/) (which extracts the domain from a URL):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[parseURL]  (@strURL varchar(1000))
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
IF CHARINDEX('http://',@strURL) > 0 OR CHARINDEX('https://',@strURL) > 0
SELECT @strURL = REPLACE(@strURL,'https://','')
SELECT @strURL = REPLACE(@strURL,'http://','')
SELECT @strURL = REPLACE(@strURL,'www','')
-- Remove everything after "/" if one exists
IF CHARINDEX('/',@strURL) > 0 (SELECT @strURL = LEFT(@strURL,CHARINDEX('/',@strURL)-1))    
RETURN @strURL
END
```

Using this SQL command:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as theCount, dbo.parseURL(url) as url FROM hit
WHERE url IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY dbo.parsedomain(url)
ORDER BY thecount DESC
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[dbo].[parseURL] (@strURL varchar(1000)) RETURNS varchar(1000) AS BEGIN IF ' at line 1
```

I am relatively new to both SQL and MySQL, so not sure if the error is SQL-general or MySQL-specific. What am I missing?

Comment: The function is for SQL Server, using TSQL - it will never work as-is on MySQL.

Comment: Interesting. What would you recommend using MySQL, then?

Comment: Yup. Working on a MySQL version... Now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the equivalent MySQL function:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION parseURL(strURL VARCHAR(200)) 
  RETURNS varchar(200) 
BEGIN

  IF INSTR(strURL, 'http://') > 0 OR INSTR(strURL, 'https://') > 0 THEN
    SET strURL = REPLACE(strURL,'https://','');
    SET strURL = REPLACE(strURL,'http://','');
    SET strURL = REPLACE(strURL,'www','');
    -- Remove everything after "/" if one exists
    IF INSTR(strURL, '/') > 0 THEN 
     SET strURL = LEFT(strURL, INSTR(strURL, '/')-1);
   END IF;
  END IF;

  RETURN strURL;
END
```

Use this query:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as theCount, 
         parseURL(url) as url 
    FROM hit
   WHERE url IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY parseURL(url)
ORDER BY thecount DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Jesus Christ Ponies, effort wasted, but here it is:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION DOMAIN (url VARCHAR(255)) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
   DECLARE pos INT;
    SET pos := LOCATE('://', url);
    SET url := CASE WHEN pos=0 THEN url ELSE SUBSTR(url, pos+3) END;
    SET url := REPLACE(url,'www.',''); 
    RETURN SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 1);
   END
```

Then query:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as theCount,    
         DOMAIN(url) as url    
    FROM hit   
   WHERE url IS NOT NULL   
GROUP BY url   
ORDER BY thecount DESC
```

My function has the advantage of stripping any protocol, https, http, ftp, whatever

Comment: +1: I think yours is more efficient - I was just doing a quick & dirty change.

Comment: @OMG Probably. I pulled a bunch of random URLs from some urllist.txt files (about 25000 of them) and ran the functions. Mine got an average of around 0.52s, yours around 0.73s.